# Java - Reversing a Singly LinkedList with a for loop

Tags: java, linked-list, reverse

So the challenge right now is to try and take a LinkedList L and create a new LinkedList Reverse with the reverse of L. I need to accomplish this with a forloop. This is what I have so far:

```
public void ReverseL(Intco obj) {
    ListNode p = obj.c;
    ListNode RevL = c;
    int index = obj.get_howmany();
    if (obj.c != null) {
        while (this.get_howmany() != obj.get_howmany()) {
            p = obj.c;
            for (int i = index; i <= 0; i--) {
                p = p.link;
            }
            RevL = new ListNode(p.info, RevL);
            howmany++;
            index--;
        }
    }
    c = RevL;
}
```

Intco is the class I am working with. Howmany is the counter for how many integers are in the LinkedList (It is incremented by the insert method I made).

Let's say I add 4 integers to L, so L will contain:
    L -> 5 -> 12 -> 25 -> 15 -> null

howmany = 4 for L.

The forloop is going to go through L until it hits the 4th value, insert that 4th value to RevL. Go through L again, but hits 3rd value (25) now, then insert 3rd value to RevL.

The problem I am running into is my output is:

```
Reverse of L (Reverse): 
15
15
15
15

P: 
15
25
12
5
```

Just in case, here is the private class for the LinkedList:

```
private class ListNode {

    private int info;
    private ListNode link;

    public ListNode() {
        info = 0;
        link = null;
    }

    public ListNode(int i, ListNode next) {
        info = i;
        link = next;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it just repeats the last integer I have in the original linkedlist. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `Intco  L` here?

Comment: It's taking in an object L of Intco that contains a LinkedList. @Bunti I changed it to obj to make it a bit more clear. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with one `while` loop and `for ` loop? And also when you iterate in the reverse order you try to access `next` link of the current node which does not exists in the first run of the loop. But you need to have a way to access each element by index so that you can easily access the actual previous node. Because this is a singly linked list you cannot loop in reverse order and access next element with `next` element

Comment: With the 'while' loop, I want everything to stop after RevL contains the same amount of integers as the obj being passed through the method. The 'for 'loop is to iterate through the obj that is passed through.

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
for (int i = index; i <= 0; i--) {
            p = p.link;
        }
```

to

```
for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--) {
            p = p.link;
        }
```

Comment: It throws a java.lang.NullPointerException error. I'm adding more details above right now

Comment: is it thrown at line
p=p.link?

Comment: Yeah, it's at p=p.link

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function named get(int index). Run the for loop through it.
This get function will traverse the n, n-1, n-2, ... ,2,1.

Say you have a list of size 10. Loop goes like this:

```
for(int i=size; i>0; i-- {
   get(index);
}
```

Now how to implement get(int index). Since its a singly linked list. There is no way other than to traverse the list from 1st to the desired index.